# Reading and Parsing Files in .NET - Performance For Hire

Tags: .net, performance, file

I want the most performat way to read and parse a file.

Is it possible to read a file in .NET, but not load the entire file into memory?  i.e. just load the file line by line as I parse the content of each row?

Does XmlTextReader load the entire file into memory or does it stream the file into memory as it reads the file?

Comment: most perfomat = best performing

Answer (score 10):

You could use the ReadLine method of StreamReader Class:

```
string line;

// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file = 
   new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");

while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine (line);
}

file.Close();
```

For XML files I would go with XMLTextReader. See this [article on Dr. Dobb's Journal](http://www.ddj.com/windows/184416669):

*"**Parsing XML Files in .NET Using C#:** Five different parsing techniques are available in .NET, and each has its own advantages"*

Answer (score 1):

XmlTextReader works on a stream - so it does not read the whole file in memory.

Answer (score 1):

here is a TextFileReader Class I have been using for years

http://www.dotnet2themax.com/ShowContent.aspx?ID=4ee44d6c-79a9-466d-ab47-56bba526534f

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about XMLTextReader, but  you can read a file line by line using the FileReader objects. )

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is using the StreamReader.ReadLine function and test the performance compared to things like FileStream/TextReader.

Comment: StreamReader inherits from TextReader (which is abstract class), so you can not compare their performance.

Comment: Good call, didn't realize that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the XMLTextReader either, but you can read line by line like this:

```
Dim theLine as String
Dim fsFile As New FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open)   'File Stream for the Input File
Dim fsImport As New FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)  'File Stream for the Output File
Dim srFile As New StreamReader(fsFile)  'Stream Reader for Input File
Dim swfile As New StreamWriter(fsImport)   'Stream Writer for Output File

Do While srFile.Peek <> -1              'Do While it's not the last line of the file
    theLine = srFile.ReadLine           'Read the line
    Messagebox.Show(theLine, "Line-by-Line!")
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

XmlTextReader does not load the entire file into memory, it operates on a stream.

All of filestream objects read the file in "chunks".
You can specify how much data (i.e. how big a chunk) to bring back to your program with each call (i.e. m bytes, where m is any integer - possibly long - value, or with a text reader, a single line of arbitrary length)
The OS will cache n bytes (where n is 0 some or all) per read for performance reasons. 
You have absolutely no control over the size of n, and will only frustrate yourself experimenting to find out what it is, as it changes due to a thousand different environmental factors.

Comment: questions don't seem to be tagged based on level though? for that to be effective, you would need a built-in grading system when submitting questions like easy medium hard beginner advanced guru-level etc hehe.

Comment: Hes just worried about the binary.